# Ito Taylor expansion examples

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion

Is there any one can provide me some references that handle numerical examples of solving Stochastic Differential Equations SDE by Ito Taylor expansion method.

Comment: How does this method work...? Never heard of it before.

Comment: @ saz, Take a look at the book "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differ-
ential Equations", of the authors P. E. Kloeden and E. Platen, section 10.6 www.springer.com/la/book/9783540540625.